# Calling Static Member Function on Class Stored as String in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

Since I am aware that one can call a member function on Class stored as String. But I was wondering if there is any way to do the same for static member function in PHP.
for example:

```
class A
{
   public static function run(){
       echo "OK";
   }
}

"A"::"run"()
```

Something similar to the above example. 
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To tackle this type of problem, which I faced while developing a user-friendly PHP framework, is to store the class name and static method name as a string in some PHP variables.

```
$className = "A";
$methodName = "run";
```

And call it like so:

```
$className::$methodName();
```

or second way

```
$func = "A::run";
$func(); //or
"A::run"();
```

And this is how one calls the static method on the class stored as a string.
This one of the ways, more can be found at https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-dynamically-invoke-a-class-method-in-php

Answer (score -1):

you can call class as string like this

```
<?php
class A 
{
    public static function run()
    {
        echo "OK";
    }   
}

$stringClass = "A";
$staticMethod = "run";

$stringClass::$staticMethod();
```